# Far Call to code segment on the x86

Tags: c, exception, assembly, x86, memory-segmentation

I am trying to do a far call from a task with a flat code seg , flat data seg and of ring 0 privilege level to another code segment with the same privilege level at offset zero, but I do get a GP fault.

How I do the far call:

```
__asm__ volatile ("lcall *%0" :: "m" (ptr));
```

where ptr is a variable of the following data (far_ptr_t):

```
  typedef struct {

    void* offset;
    uint16_t sel;

} __attribute__((packed)) far_ptr_t;
```

When i debug it i see that it fails on the call instruction, is there any reason i should consider in order to know why i get a GP fault ?

Comment: hm, can you, in principle, reach the memory location pointed to by offset?

Comment: explanation: this looks "proper" to me. You're not in real mode, ie. you've got memory protection that inhibits you from accessing memory not mapped into your processes' memory

Comment: Have you tried this in BOCHS, where you can single-step the virtual machine from the outside?  Its built-in debugger might possibly also show you the reason for the #GP fault.

Comment: you don't even have to dig so deep. It's a GP fault. That describes exactly what's wrong.

Comment: You sure the segment selector you are using has a valid entry in the GDT (or LDT). This isn't a minimal verifiable example so hard to tell exactly what your error is beyond the usual suspects that cause a GP.

Comment: In the debugger, can you read the memory using as address the contents of `m`?

Comment: @MichaelPetch I am sure that the selector is placed in the GDT and having a valid entry.

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes, the memory location is within an acceptable region in SRAM...

Comment: "Region in sram" points to you thinking in physical addresses, yet you should only see gp faults when you're in a mode where there's address translation. Something doesn't line up here. Are you in real mode or are you not?

Comment: @MarcusMüller the only address translation happening is from logical to linear address, I do consider my linear address to be the physical address because paging is disabled. so yes the linear address I am seeing refers to the physical address which in fact relays within the SRAM range. what do you mean something doesn't line up here ?

Comment: I must admit that I'm at the end of my wits, but all the valuable info in your setting you've been giving in your comments should really be part of your question, and you should include a full minimal example that people can try themselves

Comment: @MarcusMüller your right with that, the problem with writing an example that there is a lot of setup for system tables, system data types and it would be so huge to put it here ... i just thought my may of calling the code segment is wrong , since i can do far calls to tasks and it works fine but i get this problem only with independent code segments, thanks for your help tho